# How to prevent user from selecting worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to prevent user from selecting worksheet based on result of "if contidition"?
For exsample, I have several sheets in one workbook, and if the result of a specific range is "no result to display"' the user wont be able to select the worksheet "market values".
Insted he will get a msgbox :"There are no values to display".
MANY THANKS!!

Comment: I think the best way to do such a thing would be to have a Worksheet_Change event that would hide/unhide worksheets based on values in specific ranges. That way the user won't have to search for worksheets which he can view.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the worksheet activate event. What you could do is this: on the worksheet activate event you update a variable that holds the last active worksheet if the user can see the worksheet. And if the user shouldn't see the activated worksheet you show a message box and reactivate the last active worksheet. Pseudocode would be something like this:

```
if the user can see the currently activated worksheet
    remember the worksheet as the last active one
else
    display message box
    activate the last active worksheet
```

Answer (score 0):

To protect a sheet you should add a Worksheet_Activate event handler to the sheet.  To do this go to vba and in the project navigator click on the worksheet (in Microsoft Excel Objects). This brings you to a code window for the sheet. Add the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    MsgBox "private"
End Sub
```

This always activates Sheet1 and displays a warning to the user.

Comment: There might not be a sheet called `"Sheet1"` so perhaps `Sheets(1).Activate` works best assuming the first sheet isn't the one that's protected (so you probably also need an if for that)...